# Subquery inside INNER JOIN (MySQL Workbench)

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, inner-join

I'm working on a relational database with information for video games and their users. I want to create a view that displays the first name, last name and email of users that play a particular game (e.g. FIFA 22).

There are three tables in my database:

1. The table "NAME" contains the id (`id_game`), the name (`name`) and description (`description`) for each game.
2. The table "PLAY" contains the id (`id_game`) for each game and the id (`id_system_user`) for each user.
3. The table "SYSTEM_USER" contains the id (`id_system_user`), the first name (`first_name`), the last name (`last_name`) and the email (`email`) for each user

I've tried creating the view and then using a subquery inside an INNER JOIN to join the three tables but I get an error every time I execute it. The code is the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vw_FIFA22 AS
    (SELECT S.first_name AS "First name",
            S.last_name AS "Last name",
            S.email AS "E-Mail"
     FROM SYSTEM_USER AS S
     INNER JOIN (SELECT G.name AS "Game name",
                        P.id_system_user AS "System user"
                 FROM GAME AS G
                 INNER JOIN PLAY AS P ON (G.id_game = P.id_game)
                 WHERE G.name = "FIFA 22") AS N
     ON (S.id_system_user = N.id_system_user)
    );
```

and the error is:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'N.id_system_user' in 'on clause'
```

Then I tried running the next code and worked out:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vw_FIFA22 AS
    (SELECT S.first_name,
            S.last_name,
            S.email
     FROM SYSTEM_USER AS S
     INNER JOIN PLAY AS P
     ON (S.id_system_user = P.id_system_user)
     WHERE id_game = (SELECT id_game
                      FROM GAME
                      WHERE name = "FIFA 22")
    );
```

Also, after reading the answers for this question ([MySQL INNER JOIN with SubQuery (well detailed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39536195/mysql-inner-join-with-subquery-well-detailed)), I tried running this other variation and it also worked:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vw_FIFA22 AS
    (SELECT S.first_name AS "First name",
            S.last_name AS "Last name",
            S.email AS "E-Mail"
     FROM (SELECT P.id_system_user
           FROM GAME AS G
           INNER JOIN PLAY AS P ON (G.id_game = P.id_game)
           WHERE G.name = "FIFA 22") AS P
     INNER JOIN SYSTEM_USER AS S
     ON S.id_system_user = P.id_system_user
    );
```

Why did these two variations work out well but the first code didn't?

Comment: The first query fails because the subquery aliases column `id_system_user` to `"System user"`, so the former name is not available in the `ON` clause of the join. You can just remove the aliasing.

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Comment: This post is here forever to help others, please consider editing to improve it per the site help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to join the 3 tables together, there is no need for subqueries e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vw_FIFA22 AS
(SELECT S.first_name AS "First name",
        S.last_name AS "Last name",
        S.email AS "E-Mail"
 FROM SYSTEM_USER AS S
 INNER JOIN PLAY AS P ON S.id_system_user = P.id_system_user
 INNER JOIN GAME G ON G.id_game = P.id_game
 WHERE G.name = "FIFA 22"
 ;
```

Comment: Syntax error. (Remove the `(` from the beginning of the 2:nd row.)

Comment: @NickW Thanks for your help! I'm still new in SQL and I didn't know I could use JOIN statements like that!